# MySql update and deletes extremely slow

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have enabled the slow_query_log in my.cnf.

There are no select queries in the log. They are all updates, deletes and inserts which take several seconds on very small tables.

Here are a couple of examples from the slow query log analysed with dumpslow:

```
Count: 33  Time=2.96s (97s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), dbuser[dbuser]@localhost
  UPDATE `users` SET `lockout_time` = NULL WHERE `users`.`id` = N

Count: 116  Time=2.82s (327s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=0.0 (0), dbuser[dbuser]@localhost
  DELETE FROM `client_searches` WHERE `client_searches`.`organisation_id` = N AND (session_id = N )
```

Note that the tables 'users' and 'client_searches' are very small INNODB tables (494 rows and 206 rows respectively)

I dont know if I have made a complete blunder in the my.cnf or something (posted below). The server is Ubuntu 14.04 VPS with 2Gb of memory. I am trying to work out how to debug this issue.

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

bind-address        = 127.0.0.1

key_buffer      = 500K
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 40

table_open_cache        = 800
table_definition_cache = 400

query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 64M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
log_slow_queries    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1

expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 600M

tmp_table_size = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M


[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Table description for client searches ~300 rows but deleted and re-inserted regularly when users perform a search. Always appears in slow queries with insert times of several seconds.

```
CREATE TABLE `client_searches` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `known_as_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ethnicity_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iwi_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `programme_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `exit_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_age_from` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_age_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_date_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_date_to` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `suburb_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `school_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `issue_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exit_date_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `exit_date_to` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `referral_source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort_order` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `activation_date_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `activation_date_to` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `assessment_date_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `assessment_date_to` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_assessed` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `drafts_exist` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `form_process` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_process_state` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `exclude_client_status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `signed_off_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `not_signed_off` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `no_contact_weeks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active_weeks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `waitlist_weeks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `breakdown_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondary_breakdown_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `reminder_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `waitlist_range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `multi_programmes` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `active_during_period_start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `active_during_period_end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `organisation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age_range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `case_duration_range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_to_exit_range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `town_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exclude_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `multi_status` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `outcome_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nhi` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_spent_range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `territorial_authority_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `income_source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `population_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `abuse_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `abuse_duration_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age_when_abused_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_role_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `needs_met_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_abuse_history_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `perpetrator_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `threats_violence_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `childcare_provided_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transport_provided_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funding_source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exclude_statuses` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `family_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `multi_family_status` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `enrolled_with_pho_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_or_adult_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referral_end_code_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referral_to_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `pregnant_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `consent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `specific_referrer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `specific_referrer2_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=513018 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Table description for clients table ~30,000 rows (never appears in slow queries)

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `programme_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `exit_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `referral_source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondary_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `school_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activation_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exited_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `related_client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assessment_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `assessed_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `core_updated_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `signed_off_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `signed_off_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reminder_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reminder_text` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `waitlist_range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organisation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age_range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `case_duration_range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_to_exit_range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_spent_range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `income_source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `territorial_authority_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `population_group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `abuse_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `abuse_duration_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age_when_abused_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_role_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `needs_met_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_abuse_history_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `perpetrator_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `threats_violence_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `linked_client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outcome_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `childcare_provided_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transport_provided_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `funding_source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `family_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `family_client` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_family_client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enrolled_with_pho_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_or_adult_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referral_end_code_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referral_to_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `pregnant_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `consent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `specific_referrer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `specific_referrer2_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_clients_on_person_id` (`person_id`),
  KEY `index_clients_on_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `index_clients_on_programme_id` (`programme_id`),
  KEY `index_clients_on_organisation_id` (`organisation_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48099 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears my problem was more related to very slow disk IO.

When I ran:
dd bs=1M count=256 if=/dev/zero of=test conv=fdatasync
I got a result of less than 20 MB/s

I moved to a new host and got over 300 MB/s and no longer have a problem.

My hosting company recommended that I make the following changes to my.cnf

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_file_per_table=ON
innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC
```

I made the changes but it made no real difference whereas the move to a new server was like .. well .. a new server!

Answer (score 0):

The things that spring to mind are:

- Make sure you have indexes on all columns which you are selecting on. I would have the following: (`users.id`), (`organisation_id`), (`session_id`), and perhaps if this is going to become a massive table, (`organisation_id`, `session_id`), i.e. a two-column index, which for tables your size is definitely not necessary.
- Make sure whatever instance you are running on doesn't have a cap on I/O on the disc you are using to store your data, so for example if it is an AWS micro and performance is important you should really up it a bit.

Your my.cnf looks fine, given that you have such small tables: you definitely don't need to optimise your config for this. Just make sure that you aren't loading the disc with lots of other write operations while trying to do these operations.

Comment: The thing that puzzles me is that the entries in the slow queries log are for updates on tables with several hundred rows whereas selects on the tables with hundreds of thousands are not appearing in the log.

Comment: That's interesting. Can you post a `show create table` for `users` and `client_searches`, as well as a table that's much quicker?

Comment: Edited question to add a couple of table descriptions

Comment: Yeah, you don't have indexes on `client_searches.organisation_id` and `client_searches.session_id` - these will greatly improve performance. Have you made `users.id` the primary key? If you have already, and the queries still take ages then something very strange is going on...What kind of hardware are you running on?

Comment: The slow stuff are inserts into client searches. Indexes would make inserts slower.

Comment: Indexes make only a tiny difference to insert speed, effectively negligible in my experience. The speed gain on SELECTs more than makes up for it. The fact that your updates and deletes are taking seconds suggests they would be more good than harm. The biggest performance improvement you can give your system though would be to switch to SSD (assuming the extra cost isn't an issue), which given the information you've provided I'm assuming you haven't. On this note though, how slow are your inserts?